# Stop hover when anchor is shown

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show anchor on just above table, display on `hover` of the thead, and again hide on `mouseout` from thead. I have did with this with `mouseover` and `mouseout` events but the problem is that when I am trying to take mouse over the anchor it blinks because the `mouseout` event is still being fired. I want to show the anchor and trying to able click the anchor when it is shown.

This is my sample code:

```
<a href="#" class="anchor" style="display:none">test</a>
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
         </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- other code --> 
</table>
```

Comment: So you have to rethink this. You want to hide the link when you `mouseout` the `thead` but you want to be able to click the link??? Maybe give the `mouseout` a `setTimeout` before it actually hides the link so you have time hover over it?

Comment: Your plan is ridiculous.  Notice that the anchor is outside the table.  You will show the anchor when the user hovers over the table then hide the anchor when they actually attempt to click it, because to get to the anchor the mouse must leave the table.

Comment: His plan is not ridiculous, just hard to achieve, I have a fiddle right now I am making. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: I've added a fiddle now, you can test it, the code is in the answer I have written, as you can see, this is achievable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much all guys. All of you tried to help me. I really appreciate. I solved this issue. i Did something like this:-

When the hover was out of the thead the anchor was blinking as the mouseout event was firing and trying to hide anchor. So I called mouseover on anchor also to show anchor.

```
$('thead', 'a').mouseover(function () {
                $('a').show();
            });
            $('thead', 'a').mouseout(function () {
                $('a').hide();
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question because I've had problems like this in the past.

In this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/dfuxuad1/1/), I have two elements the upper one is a styled anchor, and the lower one a div like your table.

The mouseover and mouseout events use both elements.

I wonder if this might work for you.

JS

```
$('.table1, .showme').mouseover( function(){
       $('.showme').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.table1, .showme').mouseout( function(){
       $('.showme').css('display', 'none');
});
```

---

Here's a second [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/dfuxuad1/2/) with a large table and the actions only active over the header.

Comment: thanks very much for your answer in your second fiddle do you have seen some blinking ?

Comment: Yes, the blinking is because the arrow hits the border of the table. You can remove the border, or you could put both elements in a div and lower the popup div 1 pixel so it overlaps the theader. There are many ways you can "adjust" the elements so that there is no blinking.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/xp9zjcr1/

You can remove the border on the `.hoverableDiv` class, I added it to show you the selection area.

What I've done is I've wrapped your links (`<a>`) in a div with the class `.hoverableDiv`, which is set as `position:fixed;`. In JS I count the number of items in the `.th` class and I get the location and sizes of the `.th` class items (I've added `class="th"` to your `<th>` tags (add it only if you want a link for it, you can leave the class out and it will not have a hover effect with link). From here, I take each item in the `.hoverableDiv` class and set its location and size within the document to match that of the item with `.th` class that matches its index. Then I set the properties for the mouseover and the properties for mouseout.

The effect is: the link hides on document ready is shown on mouseover and hides again on mouseout. The div surrounding the link expands and retracts to the correct position during these events

**HTML**

```
<div class="expandForHover"></div>
<table cellspacing="5px">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="th">First</th>
            <th class="th">Second</th>
            <th class="th">Third</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td>this</td>
        <td>this2</td>
        <td>this2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="hoverableDiv"><a href="#" class="anchor">test</a>

</div>
<div class="hoverableDiv"><a href="#" class="anchor">test2</a>

</div>
<div class="hoverableDiv"><a href="#" class="anchor">test3</a>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
table {
    background-color:#123456;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
thead {
    background-color:#aaaaaa;
}
.hoverableDiv {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:none;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.anchor {
    background-color:#999999;
}
```

**JS**

```
var hovDivHeight = $(".hoverableDiv").height();
var tableSpacing = parseInt($("table").attr("cellspacing"), 10);

var numItems = $(".hoverableDiv").length;
$(".anchor").hide();

for (i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    var thLeft = $(".th:eq(" + i + ")").offset().left;
    var thTop = $(".th:eq(" + i + ")").offset().top;
    var thW = $(".th:eq(" + i + ")").width();
    var thH = $(".th:eq(" + i + ")").height();

    $(".hoverableDiv:eq(" + i + ")").css({
        left: thLeft + "px",
        width: thW + "px",
        top: thTop + "px",
        height: hovDivHeight + "px"
    });
}
$(".hoverableDiv").mouseover(function () {
    var aHeight = $(".anchor").height();
    var index = $(this).index()-2;
    $(this).css({
        height: hovDivHeight + tableSpacing+ thH + "px",
        top: thTop -thH -tableSpacing + "px"
    });
    $(".anchor:eq(" + index + ")").show();
});

$(".hoverableDiv").mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css({
        height: hovDivHeight + "px",
        top: thTop + "px"
    });
    $(".anchor").hide();
});
```

**EDIT**

---

I've added this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ctwheels/xp9zjcr1/2/ which has basic styling, and removes the border as I mentioned you should do above.

---

Comment: thanks very much bro. I have little complication is that i have image in anchor and I have set image's position (with position:realtive and have set top and left of image ) on corner of thead. So when I hover on thead the anchor is shown but when I am trying to click that image the mouseout event is fired and image is hide